# The express server is called to localhost:5001, but not 192.168.219.111

Tags: firebase, express, server

index.js is below .

> import { https } from 'firebase-functions';
> import express from "express";

> import houseRoute from './src/houseRouter.js';

> import userRoute from '../src/userRouter.js';

> export const house = https.onRequest(houseRoute);

> export const user = https.onRequest(userRoute);
>
> houseRouter.js is below
>
> import express from "express"
> import request from 'request'
> import {xml2json} from './common/common.js'
> import {db, serviceKey} from './common/constant.js'
>
> const router = express.Router();
>
> router.post('/houseList', function(req, res, next){
>
> let body = req.body;
> getHouseList(res, body);
>
> });

I don't know why I can't call with IP
Experts. please Help me

I try below

> import { https } from 'firebase-functions';
> import express from "express";
> import houseRoute from './src/houseRouter.js';
> import userRoute from './src/userRouter.js';
>
> const app = express();
> app.listen(5001, "0.0.0.0");
>
> export const api = https.onRequest(app);
> export const house = https.onRequest(houseRoute);
> export const user = https.onRequest(userRoute);

but I still couldn't call with IP

Comment: Is the server work with `localhost:5001`?

Comment: Yes. It works well on localhost:5001

Comment: The ip address is your local ip add?

Comment: I am sorry . I solved  my problem. It was the problem of firebase.

Comment: I add below in firebase.json
 "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "host": "192.168.***.***",
      "port": 5001
    },
  },